# How to add two news fields to a large csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have two large csv files. One is a subset of the other one (but not in the same order) but with two new fields added at the end.  For example:

File one:

```
a, b, c
b, a, c
a, c, d
c, a ,a
```

File two:

```
c, a, a, g, i
b, a, c, f, g
```

I would like to make a new version of file one which has these new fields where they exist in file two.  E.g.

Modified file one:

```
a, b, c,, 
b, a, c, f, g
a, c, d,,
c, a ,a, g, i
```

In pandas I can read them both in, although they are large, with

```
df1 = pandas.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2 = pandas.read_csv("file2.csv")
```

How can I create the modified file one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", header=None)
df1.merge(df2, on=[0,1,2], how='left').to_csv('file3.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

To keep records from both dfs use:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=[0,1,2], how='outer')
```

And if you have more columns you can use `columns.tolist()` to avoid hard typing:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=df1.columns.tolist(), how='outer')
```

Comment: What does it do with records from the smaller set which it doesn't find in the large one? Does it just ignore them?

Comment: `how='left'` will ignore them. `how='outer'` will include them.

Comment: Is there any way to get a list of which records would have been included by `how='outer'` but not `'how=left'` ?  Maybe I should ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.merge as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
modified_df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

by default, merge will use the intersection of the two dataframe to perform the join if `on` is not defined in the call.

### Example

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'],['b', 'a', 'c'],['a', 'c', 'd'],['c', 'a' ,'a']])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([['c', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'i'],['b', 'a', 'c', 'f', 'g']])
>>> df1.merge(df2, how='left') 
   0  1  2    3    4
0  a  b  c  NaN  NaN
1  b  a  c    f    g
2  a  c  d  NaN  NaN
3  c  a  a    g    i
>>>
```

Then you can write the `modified_df1` back to a csv file like:

```
modified_df1.to_csv('modified_file.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. Say we had `df2 = pd.DataFrame([['c', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'i'],['b', 'a', 'c', 'f', 'g'],  ['a','a','a','d','e']])` instead. Can pandas report that `['a','a','a','d','e']` was not joined by `df1.merge(df2, how='left')` ?

Comment: @eleanora what do you mean by 'report that ['a','a','a','d','e'] was not joined' ?

Comment: If you do `df1.merge(df2, how='left') ` with the new df2 then that record is just discarded it seems. It would be good to know which records from df2 are discarded.